# How can i upload Gitlab artifacts to a external shared folder?

Tags: gitlab, yaml

Actually I was facing one issue where every time I need to download Gitlab artifacts after pipeline done and upload those artifacts to Shared folder(Teams shared folder).
Can someone suggest if there is any way that we can include path of Shared folder link(External link) in .gitlab-ci.yml File, so that my artifacts pushes/copies to External shared folder directly after pipeline completed.
Please share suggestions.

I tried to looking to Gitlab documentation but not getting right direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.